# Is there a way to convert a hex value to an 8-digit format without losing leading zeros in Python 3.x?

Tags: python-3.x, hex

I've a hex value: "0000019c".
I want increased hex value as: "0000019d".
but I get value as: "0x19d"
I need the hex value as: "0000019d" only.

I've tried this code:

```
counter = "0000019c"
i = int(counter, 16)
i += 1
print(hex(i))
```

but as I've mentioned, it gives me just like this: "0000019d". and I need this in eight digit hex format as I've mentioned as may be I can get an 8 digit counter.

Comment: `f"{i:08x}"` should do what you want?

Comment: Yes, your guess was right. It gives me what I want. Thanks!!!

Comment: how to store it in variable? var_b = (inc:08x) isn't working.

Comment: `var_b = f"{inc:08x}"`